# AngularJS: Pass info from Controller to Service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

Is there a way to pass info from a controller to service? I know that you should pass info from the service to the controller, but let me explain you my problem:

I have two screens (or two views) with different controller but with the same module. Let's name them: ControllerOne with ViewOne and ServiceOne AND ControllerTwo with ViewTwo and ServiceTwo.

`ServiceOne` makes an http request to get some json data (from a remote origin). In `ControllerOne` I have a function where it calls the ServiceOne to get all data and in the ViewOne I show the list of all videos fetched from the remote origin (from ControllerOne).

The code for `ServiceOne` is shown above:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp.MyModule')
    .factory('ServiceOne', ServiceOne);

ServiceOne.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];


function ServiceOne($http, $q) {

    var url = 'https://THE_LINK_I_WANT_TO_GET_DATA_FROM';
    var result = [];

    var service = {
        getAllVideos: getAllVideos,
        getVideo: getVideo
    };
    return service;


    function getAllVideos(callback){
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data) {
                result = data.result;
                callback(result);
            });
    }

    function getVideo(videoId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i].videoId === videoId) {
                return $q.when(result[i]);
            }
        }
        return $q.when(null);
    }

}
})();
```

The `ControllerOne` looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp.MyModule')
        .controller('ControllerOne', ControllerOne);

        ControllerOne.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'ServiceOne'];

        function ControllerOne($scope, $state, ServiceOne) {


            var vm = angular.extend(this, {
                videos: [],
                navigateToVideo: navigateToVideo
            });


            ServiceOne.getAllVideos(function(data){
                vm.videos = data;
            });


            function navigateToVideo(videoId) {
                $state.go('app.video', { videoId: videoId } );
            }


        }

})();
```

On `ViewOne`, everytime someone clicks on a video, I navigate them to another view (`ViewTwo` in my case) and a parameter is passed (a unique id).

The `ControllerTwo` looks like this:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp.MyModule')
    .controller('ControllerTwo', ControllerTwo);

    ControllerTwo.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'ServiceOne'];

    function ControllerTwo($scope, $state, $stateParams, ServiceOne) {


        var vm = angular.extend(this, {
            video: []
        });


        (function init(){
            loadData();
        })();


        function loadData(){    
            var videoId = String($stateParams.videoId);
            ServiceOne.getVideo(videoId)
                .then(function(video) {
                    vm.video = video;
                });  
        }


    }

})();
```

In the `ControllerTwo` I save the parameter passed from `ControllerOne`, and save it on `videoId`. Then I call a function of `ServiceOne` to get the object I was looking for.

**So, my question is:**

Can I pass the object `vm.video` of the `ControllerTwo` to `ServiceTwo`, so I can use it in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: Services are singletones so until you reload your app, you can store vm.video in you ServiceTwo. You could also use localStorage, sessionStorage or $http cache... it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Services are MADE for sharing stuff(data and methods) across you application. So, to answer your question simply: absolutely, yes you can pass your object to your service. And, it couldn't be any easier...

ServiceOne & ServiceTwo can be accessed by ANY controller, and if you want to "pass something" to a service it's as simple as this:

```
ControllerOne.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'ServiceOne', 'ServiceTwo'];
function ControllerOne($scope, $state, ServiceOne, ServiceTwo) {

  function loadData(){    
    var videoId = String($stateParams.videoId);
    ServiceOne.getVideo(videoId)
    .then(function(video) {
      vm.video = video;
      ServiceTwo.video = video; //bam, you're done
    });  
  }
}
```

The video will persist until you restart the app.

```
ControllerOne.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'ServiceOne', 'ServiceTwo'];
function ControllerOne($scope, $state, ServiceOne, ServiceTwo) {
  // now you can access it from your other controller
  var videoStoredInServiceTwo = ServiceTwo.video;
}
```

The only thing to be aware of is timing. You might want to check that the video exists on ServiceTwo before you try to retrieve it.

```
if( ServiceTwo.video ) {
    videoStoredInServiceTwo = ServiceTwo.video;
  }
```